# how to use jsoup on router address?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

i have a question about Jsoup library ...

i have this little program , which download ,parse and get the title of an HTML page which is `google.com` .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class HTMLParser{

   public static void main(String args[]) {


    // JSoup Example - Reading HTML page from URL

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
        title = doc.title();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Jsoup Can read HTML page from URL, title : "+title);
  }
}
```

The program is working very well,BUT the problem is :

when i try to parse a file from the ip adress `192.168.1.1`(i change the `google.com` to `192.168.1.1` which is the adress of the router):

```
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://192.168.1.1/").get();
```

it does not work and shows me the error below :

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401, URL=http://192.168.1.1/
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
at HTMLParser.main(HTMLParser.java:43)
```

first i think that the problem is related to "ussername and the password" so i change the address `192.168.1.1` to `Username:Password@192.168.1.1` :

```
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://username:password@192.168.1.1/").get();
```

but it does not work , the program read the entire line as an adress.

if someone have any idea please help me !! and thanks for everybody

Comment: See [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much saka1029;Griddoor. i read what you suggest , and it helps very much,

for me i use this solution :

```
URL url = new URL("http://user:pass@domain.com/url");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

if (url.getUserInfo() != null) {
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode   (url.getUserInfo().getBytes()));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
}

InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

from : [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java)

and used this method to read the `inputstream`:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
String theString = writer.toString();
```

from : [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

then i parse the `theString` with Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

As with saka1029, you can request the URL with authentication. Then you use `Jsoup.parse(String)` to get the `Document` object.

Or you simply use Jsoup methods to send the request and get the response:

[Getting HTML Source using Jsoup of a password protected website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677062/getting-html-source-using-jsoup-of-a-password-protected-website)

[Jsoup connection with basic access authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679916/jsoup-connection-with-basic-access-authentication)

(I usually use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary` for the Base64 conversion.)

Comment: hi , @Griddoor !! , i read some solutions , but no one work with me ... in my case i need to write the username and the password in appeared auth. dialogue window or past it in the url as i mentioned, so if you can can , give a full sollution ,please!!! and thanks for reading and replying my Question.

Comment: @M.os.i There exists different kinds of authentications, you might have to try logging in manually and capture the http packet. Then you can write program to do the same thing.